# click on link in a div without firing div.click event

Tags: jquery, onclick

Given the following html:

```
<div id="mydiv">
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>

<div id="target">
  target
</div>
```

and the following js:

```
$('#mydiv').click(function() {
  $('#target').css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

What can I do to prevent clicks on link to fire click event on parent div without affecting the functionality of clicks on div?

Here a pen to show what I mean: https://codepen.io/davideghz/pen/bWdVWg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `.stopPropagation()` on your `click` event to prevent it bubbling up:

```js
$('#mydiv a').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$('#mydiv').click(function(e) {
  $('#target').css('background-color', 'blue');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>

<div id="target">
  target
</div>
```

`.stopPropagation()` is not jQuery. Here's how to do the above script in vanilla:

```js
document.getElementById('mydiv').addEventListener('click',function(e) {
  if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
    e.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('target').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>

<div id="target">
  target
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my Q to be clearer; your code breaks the clicks on parent div. I want that clicks on div fire onClick event, while clicks on text link don't

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What do you mean by *"breaks the clicks on parent div"*? Please see updated answer. Is this what you want?

Comment: pls check the linked pen, where the parent div is bigger. I want that clicks on link do not color the #target div. Only clicks on #mydiv must color #target

Comment: your solution works fine, thanks. - is there a non-js solution as well?

Comment: No, I don't know of any. Off the top of my head, I'd have thought `onclick="(e)=>{e.stopPropagation()}"` might work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @davideghz An improvement would be to only bind one listener on click, on the parent, and check if `$(e.target).is('a')` in order to `stopPropagation()`, else... do what you want to do on parent click.